# How can I expect an exception of a type that is not visible to the unit test assembly?

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, expected-exception

If I consume a WCF service, the following example client code is generated:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ServiceFault", Namespace="http://schemas.xxx.com/2014/07/Contracts/Faults")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
internal partial class ServiceFault : MyProject.Client.WCFService.Fault { ... }
```

This code is generated with `internal` on purpose - it is not meant to be accessed outside the assembly.

If I have, for example, a unit test with the following code (the URL is invalid on purpose, it was not masked for this question):

```
MyClientWrapper.Connect("http://invalidurl.com/endpoint/service.svc")
```

It will throw an exception of type `System.ServiceModel.FaultException<MyProject.Client.WCFService.ServiceFault>`. The problem I have is that when I define my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FaultException<MyProject.Client.WCFService.ServiceFault>))]
public void ShouldFail() { ... }
```

The token `MyProject.Client.WCFService.ServiceFault` is invalid because it is defined as `internal` (again, on purpose).

**So how can I expect an exception of a type that is internal to the assembly I'm testing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). You can modify your AssemblyInfo.cs for example:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Tests.Project")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to the source assembly:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssembly")]
```